# Заварил кашу…на Swift_e_2

Tags: swift

```
как стартовать через NSTimer (and repeat with different intervals...)
пробовал...
var startTimer: NSTimer!

startTimer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Int
(arc4random_uniform(5..30) (UInt32(target: self, selector: nil,  
userInfo: nil, repeats: true)))!) 
//issue//Extra argument 'selector' in call//well done


startTimer.invalidate()  //issue//Expected declaration

компилятор = Extra argument 'selector' in call
выдал      = Expected declaration
           = Max appreciate
```

Comment: в чём именно заключается вопрос? внесите, пожалуйста, необходимые правки, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: пожалуйста, используйте информативные заголовки

Comment: и форматирование подправить бы, не надо весь вопрос оформлять как код

Comment: начните в того, что прочитайте что такое NSTimer, как он работает, и как правильно использовать `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`. Я думаю после этого вопрос отпадет сам. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/

Comment: на эту ссылку давно уже сходил...но толку...наскреб советов из инета на 230Мгб...но когда эти советы пробую в Xcode ...нашел какой-то самостоятельный SwiftyTimer на GitHub, но это надо как-то инсталировать в Cocoa...бросил... а насчет оформления и порядков на форуме - это только второй форум - первый был на iXBT когда у местных жлобов клянчил схему для ремонта телевизора - даже уже и не помню когда...@MaxMikheyenko

Comment: интересно = таймер в теле исполнительной функции запускается на 3-5 циклов нормально, (но не похоже ,что рандом отрабатывает - промежутки вроде одинаковые...) а затем начинает сокращать повтор запуска  до запусков на выполнение почти мгновенно...может это из-за Double=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Документация по NSTimer говорит, что метод `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` принимает 5 аргументов:

- seconds - время через которое таймер должен сработать
- target - объект, которому надо отправить сообщение, когда таймер сработает
- selector - сообщение, которое будет отправлено объекту (другими словами, имя метода, который надо выполнить)
- userInfo - пользовательская информация для таймера
- repeats - должен ли таймер сам запуститься заново после срабатывания

Теперь, когда все это вроде понятно, вот пример этого метода:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "someSelector", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Пример выше запустит таймер, который через 1 секунду, должен будет выполнить метод `someSelector` того же класса, который создал таймер (self), никакого userInfo не передаст и через секунду этот таймер повторится снова и так до бесконечности, пока не будет выполнен `invalidate`.

Смотрим что есть у вас:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Int (arc4random_uniform(5..30) (UInt32(target: self, selector: nil, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)))!)
```

У вас тут непойми что: сначала секунды - random не принимает range, а seconds должен быть Double (у вас будет Int или UInt32 не помню); потом нет запятой, зачем то 4 остальных аргумента взяты в скобки, почему то они все кастятся в UInt32, да еще и разворачиваются (unwrap) восклицательным знаком. Что это вообще такое? Как такое вообще можно написать в xcode с его невероятно продвинутым autocomplete?!

Далее, когда таймер сработает, ожидается, что он сработает зачем то, и что то сделает. В частности выполнит метод. У вас `selector:nil`, то есть таймер ничего не сделает, просто тихо запустится заново и опять ничего не сделает и так далее.

И маленькое уточнение насчет random: у вас сначала генерируется случайное число, и уже потом оно передается в `scheduledTimer` такие образом, каждый перезапуск таймера будет с тем же числом, а не каждый раз с новым рандомом.

Все, что я написал, вы можете разобраться сами, если прочитаете документацию. Никаких секретов тут нет.

А теперь ответ:

создать таймер:

```
var startTimer: NSTimer!

self.startTimer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(arc4random_uniform(25)+5), target: self, selector: "someSelector", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Когда таймер сработает, он выполнит метод `someSelector`  в котором вам надо перезапустить таймер с новым сгенерированным значением секунд и сделать, то зачем этот таймер вообще был создан:

```
func someSelector() {
    self.startTimer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(Double(arc4random_uniform(25)+5), target: self, selector: "someSelector", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    //сделать что то полезное    
}
```